# Регулярка для выделения текста

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Есть строка

```
text/plain; charset=KOI8-R
```

нужно выделить из неё *KOI8-R*, но строка может кончаться и другими символами, поэтому надо взять весь текст после *charset=* и выбрать все буквы и символ "-", у меня с регулярками всегда проблемы , вот пока немогу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
var text = 'text/plain; charset=KOI8-R; more';
var result = text.match(/charset=([-\d\w]+)/);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: Так я делал, проблема в том после KOI8-R может быть продолжение строки, но оно будет продолжаться символами ; или какими-то другими но уже не из группы [A-z] и -, главная проблема что я не смог сделать универсальную регулярку для JS, для PCRE выглядит так: (?<=charset=)(.*?)([^Z-z0-9-]|\Z)  но на js она неработает

Comment: @vnn198 Поправил ответ. Что касается вашего последнего варианта Z-z не очень удачная конструкция, если хотите без обойтись без классов, то лучше использовать [-a-zA-Z0-9].

Comment: в Z-z ошибся , должно быть A-z конечно, спасибо за регулярку, просто они редко нужны поэтому быстро забываются, да и эти различия между PCRE/JS тоже затрудняют изучение

Comment: В соответствии со спецификацией HTTP-заголовков нужно искать либо до `;` либо до конца строки

Comment: @ReinRaus В вопросе не сообщается, что это именно HTTP-заголовок - дословно говорится об строке, а в уточняющем комментарии автор сообщает "Так я делал, проблема в том после KOI8-R может быть продолжение строки". Я не знаю откуда эта строка и как она получается, возможно это просто соединенные между собой несколько HTTP-заголовков. Ответ составлял исходя из известной мне информации.

Comment: это вообще не http, это часть ответа почтового сервера

Comment: @vnn198, `[A-z]` - тоже неверно.

Comment: Спорить небуду, по крайне мере в PCRE версии она выбирает то что надо :)

Answer (score 2):

Для http-заголовка:

```
/charset\s*=\s*([^,;\s]+)/i
```

Для meta-тега:

```
/<meta\s+[^>]*?charset\s*=\s*["']?([-\w]+)/i
```

Подробнее: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380